# How to test for instance of httpheader using vba

Tags: excel, vba, response-headers

I'm using Excel VBA to send an API request which returns a response that can be paginated, based on number of records returned. When the response is paginated, there will be a `Link` header included in the response which provides a URI for `first`, `next`, `previous`, `last` as appropriate.

The problem I have is that I'm trying detect that header and where the header is present, I want to parse the value and perform a loop using the parsed value. However my code for trying to detect the header is returning an error.

```
Dim httpHeaders: httpHeaders = request.getAllResponseHeaders()
Debug.Print httpHeaders
If httpHeaders.Contains("Link") Then
  Dim hdrLink as String
  hdrLink = request.getResponseHeader("Link")
  Debug.Print hdrLink
End If
```

My code errors out on the `If` line with "Run-time error '424': Object required".

My `httpHeaders` print is:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 18378
ETag: ******
Status: ******
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ******
Access-Control-Request-Method: ******
X-Version: ******
Link: <******&page=5>; rel="last", <******&page=2>; rel="next"
Total: 129
Per-Page: 30
X-Request-Id: ******
X-Runtime: ******
Strict-Transport-Security: ******
Expires: ******
```

Note: where `Total` is equal to or less than `Per-Page` then `Link` will not be present.

Can someone please help me understand why my code isn't detecting the presence of `Link` and how I might parse the value associated with link so I can find the last page number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `String.Contains` in VBA. There is in VB.NET.

You can explicitly declare `httpHeaders` as `String`. Although you could use [`Instr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) to test if `Link` substring is *anywhere* within the returned string, it seems easier to just attempt to access your desired header, as the MSXML library won't complain. You will just get a `vbNullString` as the value for the missing header, which is quick to test for. See an example below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintHeaders()
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60                 'required reference Microsoft XML v6,
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With http
    
        .Open "HEAD", "https://books.toscrape.com/", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        
        Dim httpHeaders As String
        
        httpHeaders = .getAllResponseHeaders()
        
        Debug.Print httpHeaders
        
        Dim hdrLink As String, contentType As String
        
        hdrLink = .getResponseHeader("Link")
        
        If hdrLink <> vbNullString Then Debug.Print "Found Link header: " & hdrLink
        
        Debug.Print .getResponseHeader("content-type")
    End With

End Sub
```